# Closing gap between insect screen and basement window

Tags: basement, insect, screens, window-frame

I have a basement window that has an insect screen in it. But there's a lot of space around the screen.

First, the screen is not solidly fixed where it is.

Second, as you can see from the photos below. The top left of the screen is about 1 inch from the window, while the bottom left is gets narrow.

How can I fix the screen to prevent insects from coming in? Should I replace the screen with a new one, even though there's no hole in it? Can I use caulking?

I measured the window frame area and the ideal insect screen will be 22 inches by 29 inches.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the screen perfectly rectangular or is it skewed or warped?  Would it fit in *any* window?   Same question for the window -- would *any* screen fit in it?    Also -- why is the screen frame black and the window white?  It makes me think the screen was not built for the window, and maybe is just the wrong size?

Comment: Does the opposite corner of the screen fit the window? If you take the screen out of the window, will it lie flat on the floor? Are the corners of the screen reasonably square? Is the screen frame bent?

Comment: Protip: Touch your phone's screen where you want the camera to focus. We'll have less of a headache looking at these.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd want some answers as to why things are askew. Windows should always be installed squarely, so unless that screen is not rectangular it doesn't make sense that there's a tapered gap. Sort that out if you can.

Caulk is absolutely not a solution. That would be an utter disaster from both an installation perspective and in appearance. You'd be better off using duct tape.

You have a few options depending on your skill level and available materials:

- **Order a custom screen.** Local shops can build them for a reasonable price. They're not complicated.
- ***Make* a custom screen** from a readily available larger one. This involves purchasing a screen, removing the screen *spline* to detach the screen, disassembling the frame, cutting the frame to size, and rebuilding it. That may sound daunting, but it's not so bad. It's critical to keep the frame square as you reset the screening.
- **Add a rail to the screen you have**. You could use aluminum box tubing or angle, and attach it with small screws or rivets.